# Looking for Lucene index version

Tags: lucene, solr, luke

When I use Luke V3.3.0, it tells me that the Lucene index that I am opening is:

- Index version: 13172b074a7
- Index format: -11 (Lucene 3.1)

I am using Solr 3.3, I removed previously my folder /var/data/solr/myrepository before indexing. I would expect the version to be Lucene 3.3. There is no index change between Lucene 3.1 and Lucene 3.3 ? At the end of the day, I just want to make sure that my index was created using Lucene 3.3.  Any easy way to get the Lucene index version is what I am looking for.

Also field collapsing works so, if there's an index change, my index version is correct. I don't see this info either from the Solr admin page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the Lucene version being used by clicking on the [Info] link on the top of the Solr Admin page. It will take you to `http://<yourserver:port>/<instancename>/admin/registry.jsp`

The Solr and Lucene Specification and Implementation versions are listed in the top section of  the Solr Info page.

I am using Solr 3.3 and this is what I see...

```
Solr Specification Version: 3.3.0
Solr Implementation Version: 3.3.0 1139785 - rmuir - 2011-06-26 09:25:01
Lucene Specification Version: 3.3.0
Lucene Implementation Version: 3.3.0 1139782 - 2011-06-26 09:27:19
Current Time: Tue Aug 23 08:35:27 EDT 2011
Server Start Time:Mon Aug 22 14:32:28 EDT 2011
```

Comment: Those information are about the Solr/Lucene version you are running. Your index version isn't necessarily the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check `<luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_33</luceneMatchVersion>` setting in solrconfig.xml

Comment: Actually, I didn't have to change solrconfig.xml when going from 3.2 to 3.3

Comment: This has nothing to do with the version you're running. It's more about the behaviour you want it to have. You can basically ask Lucene to mimic the behaviour of an old version even if buggy.